# Mutt error SMTP session failed: read error

Tags: centos, postfix, mutt, gmail

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes

set imap_user = 'name@gmail.com'
set imap_pass = 'password'

set from='name@gmail.com'
set realname='name@gmail.com'

set folder = imaps://imap.gmail.com/
set spoolfile = imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"

set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"

set smtp_url = 'smtp://name@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/'

set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900

set smtp_pass="secrets"
```

When sending a mail got that error. Firewall also off on server and port 465 open on Security group. Is it required to install postfix with mutt?

```
Connection to smtp.gmail.com closed SMTP session failed: read error Could not send the message.
```

I can read the mails on my inbox but can't send emails. This is on my maillog,

```
Mar  1 10:20:01 appsvr2 postfix/qmgr[6075]: 9703F3F7974: from=<root@appsvr2.localdomain>, size=768, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  1 10:20:01 appsvr2 postfix/local[5970]: 9427E3F796E: to=<root@appsvr2.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar  1 10:20:01 appsvr2 postfix/qmgr[6075]: 9427E3F796E: removed
Mar  1 10:20:01 appsvr2 postfix/local[5970]: 9703F3F7974: to=<root@appsvr2.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar  1 10:20:01 appsvr2 postfix/qmgr[6075]: 9703F3F7974: removed
Mar  1 10:30:01 appsvr2 postfix/pickup[5945]: A43FB3E643: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar  1 10:30:01 appsvr2 postfix/cleanup[5980]: A43FB3E643: message-id=<20190301050001.A43FB3E643@appsvr2.localdomain>
Mar  1 10:30:01 appsvr2 postfix/qmgr[6075]: A43FB3E643: from=<root@appsvr2.localdomain>, size=827, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  1 10:30:01 appsvr2 postfix/local[5983]: A43FB3E643: to=<root@appsvr2.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar  1 10:30:01 appsvr2 postfix/qmgr[6075]: A43FB3E643: removed
```

Comment: try changing smtp_url protocol to smtps
`set smtp_url = 'smtps://name@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/'`

Comment: Now getting this error message,
SMTP session failed: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo e63sm18078854pfa.116 - gsmtp

Comment: according to message `HELO/EHLO argument invalid`, can you provide the output of `:set ?hostname`. Or even better send link to pastebin with output of command `neomutt -D -S` (shows censored configuration without sensitive variables) in case of mutt just `mutt -D` but please check you're not sharing your secrets.
----
not related to your issue: I see `password` in `smtp_url` and value of `smtp_pass`… it's not necessary to have both.

Comment: @ Jakub Jindra My host name is appsvr2. From smtp_url removed the password.And tried with zohomail. Same error.

Comment: This is on my maullog,

Comment: Now I'm confused. You're setting smtp_url in your mutt config file and posting your local postfix logs. Either

a) use smtp_url in mutt with gmail smtp server

b) configure your postfix to act as relay to gmail smtp server and then set corresponding smtp_url in mutt config to point to your postfix.

Comment: postfix removed and mutt config added  set smtp_url = 'smtp://name@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/'.

 I can read the my inbox but when sending the mail getting error. Connection to smtp.gmail.com closed, SMTP session failed: read error

Comment: did you find the fix ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a fix? (port `smtps` did nothing on my side)

Comment: I've fixed it. set smtp_url = 'smtps://name@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/'

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port in my config from `465` to `587` and was able to send emails. The correct line in your config should look like so

```
set smtp_url = 'smtp://name@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:587/'
```

Comment: smtps is preferred since its secured. `set smtp_url = "smtps://anthony@engineer.com@smtp.mail.com:465/"` is the preferred setting

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to modify your `smtp_url`. Note that smtp corresponds to port 587 and smtps corresponds to port 465.

Port 465 is preferred for security reasons. update `user@domain.com` to your email in the below line.

```
set smtp_url = "smtps://user@domain.com@smtp.mail.com:465/"
```

or

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://user@domain.com@smtp.mail.com:587/"
```